# Java check each line of strings from a text file and search if the string exist

Tags: java

Hello Im working on a program to check each line of words from text file and see if they exist

> example of execution
>
> Enter a word to search for: taco
>
> Word 'taco' was found.
>
> Enter a word to search for: asd
>
> Word 'asd' was NOT found.

This is the description for assignment

> Write a program to read in 100 words from a file. Then, have the user
>   search for a word until they enter 'quit'. The program will read in up
>   to 100 words from a file. The file may or may not contain 100 words
>   but the array should hold up to 100 (if the list does not contain
>   enough words, fill the rest of the array with empty strings). After
>   the file is read in, the program will prompt the user for a search
>   string. The program will then search for the string and tell the user
>   if the word was found or not. The program will continue to get search
>   strings from the user until the user enters 'quit'

here is my code so far and is very incomplete

I need advise or suggestion on what else I need to add/fix

thank you!

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class project2 {
  public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException {
    String[] list;
    String  search = "";


    while ( ! search.equals( "quit" ) ) 
    {
        System.out.println( "\nEnter a word to search for: " );  
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        search = input.next();
        Scanner file = new Scanner(new File("words.txt"));

   while(file.hasNextLine()){
            String str = file.nextLine();
            if(str.indexOf("search") != -1){
                System.out.println( "Word '" + search + "' was found");}

            else  System.out.println( "Word '" + search + "' was NOT found");}
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: If the file's contents do not change throughout this program, there is no need to rescan the file on each iteration of the loop.

Comment: This code will check each line as Robin pointed out, but it also checks for the character sequence anywhere on the line, but not aligned to word boundaries.  For example, searching for "taco" will match "I flew into Tacoma, WA"

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not state a specific question, but seem to be seeking advice, I will point out some flaws I see along with improvements.

Potential flaws:

1. **You are checking each line of the file instead of the entire file.**  My interpretation of your requirements, and you should verify this, is that you need to determine if the supplied word exists anywhere in the file, not which lines contain it.
2. **The only boundary you split the file on is new line** (by virtue of using readLine()).  However, I wonder why the requirement uses the word "word".  Are you supposed to split on word boundaries?  For example, if the file contains the sentence "I will arrive in Tacoma, WA", it will match a search for "Taco", which has nothing to do with the city of Tacoma.
3. **You are rescanning the entire file every time a word is entered.**  Your requirements did not state whether you need to worry about the file changing during runtime.  I would guess no, which means you can probably get away with reading it once and parsing it into an appropriate data structure.
4. **You are doing a linear scan of the file.**  It would be faster to find all the words, store them into a data structure that is optimized for quick searches.
5. **What is the required / expected behavior for lower case vs. upper case matching?** Should "taco" match "Taco"?

My suggestions:

1. Before entering the input loop, read the contents of the file, line-by-line, and split on whitespace to find "words".
2. Store each word into a data structure optimized for sub-linear search.  I'll leave it as an exercise to you to find an appropriate one.  Check the Java collections framework.
3. If you want to handle this in a case-insensitive way, then lower-case each word prior to adding it to your collection.
4. In your input loop, do a Collection.contains(o) search on the previously built collection of words to see if it occurs in the file.
5. If you want to handle this in a case-insensitive way, then lower-case the search term before calling Connection.contains(o).

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, your code checks if the word exists on each line. It needs to check if the word exists in the whole file. To fix this, you can either concatenate the line strings, or use a boolean variable to keep track of whether a word has been found yet.